# Mezzanine Media Library Missing in Admin

Tags: python, django, media, mezzanine

I have a strange problem. A client came back to me saying that they are not able to upload images for the pages after a migration to the latest Mezzanine/Django installation. Apparently, the media browser was missing in the page editing interface. Not sure if that is the problem but after a short investigation it turned out, that the media library was not present it the admin panel altogether too.

I have uncommented these lines from the settings.py file, to no avail:

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
    ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost",
        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
    ("Shop", ("shop.Product", "shop.ProductOption", "shop.DiscountCode",
        "shop.Sale", "shop.Order")),
    ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
    ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
```

the media library is still missing, and it is not found with a 404 error when trying to access it at `/admin/media-library/browse/`

I tried to create a blank brand new mezzanine project but the result was the same, the media library was missing. Any thoughts? Am I missing something straight-forward?

Answer (score 0):

I did not exactly find the source of the problem but it seemed easy enough to solve nevertheless by adding the filebrowser_safe urls to the main app urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    ("^", include("filebrowser_safe.urls")),
)
```

ADMIN_MENU_ORDER listed in the original question should remain uncommented.